# Startup script for MongoDB using EC2 user data on a launched instance

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, user-data

We have a MongoDb running in our r4.xLarge EC2 instance. I just found that every time, our instance shutsdown (for any reason) and is restarted, mongo doesn't start up as well.

We added a startup script as follows in the user data section for the EC2 instance.

```
#!/bin/bash

service mongod restart

service mongod status
```

We are still seeing the same behaviour as before, that the commands don't get executed and one needs to SSH into the instance to initiate a restart.

Can anyone point out any issue with the script or provide any specific insights regarding this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a bit of research I found that since we had NOT added the user data script during the launching of the instance the first time, I had to add a mutipart piece above the #!/bin/bash

The script now looks like this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--//
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"

#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]

--//
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"

#!/bin/bash
sudo service mongod restart
sudo service mongod status
```

Moral of the story, if you forget to add your instance user data scripts during launch time of the instance and do after the fact, append the piece above the #!/bin/bash

This is because:

- AWS uses `mime-multipart` to append the user data file.
- It also uses `scripts-user, always` to run the file.